# Default datacontext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datacontext

Having the xaml below in MainWindow.xaml:

```cs
<Window x:Class="TestDependency.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Name="someLabel" Grid.Row="0"  Content="{Binding Path=LabelText}"></Label>
    <Button Grid.Row="2"  Click="Button_Click">Change</Button>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the following code behind in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(String), typeof(MainWindow));

public int counter = 0;

public String LabelText
{
  get
  {
    return (String)GetValue(LabelTextProperty);
  }

  set
  {
    SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
  }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  LabelText = "Counter " + counter++;
}
```

I would have thought that the default `DataContext` is the code behind. But I'm forced to specify the `DataContext`. **Which `DataContext` is the default?** `Null`? I would have thought that the code behind would have been (as is the same class).

And as in this sample I'm using the code behind to modify the content of the Label, could I use directly:

```cs
someLabel.Content = "Counter " + counter++;
```

I will expect that being the code behind, it shouldn't have the UI update problem that you have if the `DataContext` is in a different class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the default value of `DataContext` is `null`, here is how it's declared in `FrameworkElement` class -

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("DataContext", typeof(object),
    FrameworkElement._typeofThis,
    (PropertyMetadata) new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged)));
```

`FrameworkPropertyMetadata` takes first param for default Value of property.

As it gets inherited by all the child controls your lable's `DataContext` remains `null` unless you specify the window data context.

and you can use `someLabel.Content = "Counter " + counter++;` in codebehind to set labels content; as such it's perfectly fine to access your controls in code behind.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are binding a property of a `Label`, unless you specify a different binding source somehow the binding engine assumes that `LabelText` is a property on that class. It cannot magically determine that because the `Label` is a descendant of a `MainWindow` the binding source should be that window, which is why you need to explicitly declare it.

It's important to note that the concepts of "data context" and "binding source" are distinct: [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) is *one way* to specify the binding source, but [there are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source) [also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) [others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname).

Comment: I though, that the binding / datacontext is inherited from the parent when not specified. Otherwise, setting the datacontext on the window class will still not produce result.

Comment: @MiyamotoAkira: Sure, it's inherited (the documentation for `DataContext` says so too). But why do you expect your `MainWindow` to be the `DataContext` of anything by default? The binding engine cannot read your mind.

Comment: I suppose because I am seeing `MainWindow` as the top of the hierarchy for this program. But then, I don't know what wpf is doing under the hood (yet :-)), and there are probably other things on top of it.

Comment: It would make sense for Window to be the default binding context, since it does house the code behind and there are in fact instances in the XAML where this does appear to occur.  For example, on a Button element, the "Click" property can simply be set to the string "btnOk_Click", and as long as that function exists on the Window's code behind like `private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`, it will be called.  In that scenario, it appears as though Window's default data context is itself.  Still, DataContext absolutely must be nullable, and I think null is the best default.